# Slow and deliberate, hauntingly beautiful classical piece (identify from score)

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Slow and deliberate, hauntingly beautiful. Can you tell me the name and composer of this piece of classical music I've tried to recreate from memory? I'll be eternally grateful, of course.

https://flat.io/score/5d1aacb3bb88a5621a57d986-classical-music-i-dont-remember-the-name-of?sharingKey=49809dab01de14f7397b3e718c444a7c1b1a18fc23d789cd06b08d06e754dac3efa96ee9b83de463f178ce36d2a6762be0d54f3bde18e55773de27a05b5d63fc

[image: Musical composition]

Answer (score 17):

This is the second movement (the *Allegretto*) of [Beethoven's Seventh Symphony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J12zprD7V1k&feature=youtu.be&t=20) [(score)](https://imslp.org/wiki/Symphony_No.7%2C_Op.92_(Beethoven%2C_Ludwig_van)). Your notation is slightly different from the Beethoven, but this is certainly the piece you're looking for.

It's definitely a worldwide favorite, and for good reason!

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: I look forward to your eternal gratitude :-)

Comment: The speed of your helpful response entitles you to nothing less!

Comment: @AndrewBailey, could you accept the answer please?

Comment: @AndrewBailey As Bebs mentioned, the correct way to express eternal gratitude on this site is to hit that little green checkmark next to the right answer. :)